# How to upload polygon data for appending to a geodatabase via a JS API web application

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-service, feature-class

After a many hours of research, I am having a hard time determining the feasibility of an application I am trying to build.

**Basic proposed functionality is: user logs in, uploads polygon (either shapefile or feature class), and is then able to attribute the feature using the new server 10.1 Feature Access capability.**

The file geodatabase to be appended is on my own ArcGIS Server instance, and is connected to an Oracle enterprise DB.

I am aware that 10.1 allows a user to build a polygon right in the application window using feature access and editing, but the nature of the geometry being submitted will not allow for that. The data will have to be created in ArcMap by the app users, and then uploaded by them to a gdb on a server my organization maintains.

While I did indeed read the accepted answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/add-shapefile-from-a-local-file-to-a-js-api-map), I see no mention there of making edits to a geodatabase which is remote from the application user, and so I am unsure that it actually addresses my issue. I would gladly be corrected on that.

I know that at least a portion of my proposed functionality will be accomplished using a geoprocessing service (the appending of the new data to the existing gdb), but its the uploading of the data where I am stumped.

I am nearly convinced that this is not quite possible using tools available in the ArcGIS API. Does anyone think it is, and have any tips on where to look?

Comment: This might be useful: http://georamblings.com/2012/02/upload-shapefile-and-view-in-a-webmap/

Answer (score 3):

Your main task is to upload the user given shapefile into your server and append it to your SDE Geodatabase.

I'm not sure if actually showing the features to your user on the web map is an actual requirement, so I'll give you two ways of doing this.

If You need to show the geometries on the map, then there are two main parts to your User Case:

1. Upload User Given Shapefile and show the Geometries on the map. You have several options here. You can follow the steps given in the [shapefile-js](https://github.com/RandomEtc/shapefile-js) project. This project is for Openlayers, so you'll have to modify it to convert the shapefile to ESRI JSON instead of GeoJSON. If you are willing to use ArcGIS Online, you can follow this sample: [Add shapefile](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html)
2. Once you have the geometries/features in your web-map, then you will have to manually add them to your features service by using the [Add features Operation](http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/SDK/REST/fsadd.html)  via an Ajax Request

If you do not need to show them on the map, you case is exactly opposite that of the example: [Clip And Ship](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000035r000000). I would look at the code given in the sample, and reverse it, so that it takes an input of a zipped shapefile and appends it to your SDE.

Comment: Thanks very much @Devdatta. I'll be using your advice to start. I may have some follow questions as I work into this, but I will try to report back how it works out either way.

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at the Uploads functionality of the GP services in 10.1 - http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/uploads.html. This is the core functionality of the Server 10.1, so you don't have to develop a new piece of functionality.